# How can I set a time-frame from 3 hours ago until now in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, datetimeoffset

I need to create a time-frame that is since 3 hours ago and before NOW by setting 2 string parameters:

```
[string] since
[string] before
```

whereas each parameter is in a DateTimeOffset format as : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z:00"

How can I set since and before parameters in PowerShell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure contains useful methods, like `.AddHours()` and `.ToString()`. Just add -3 hours to current date. Use the standard date and time [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to get desired output or roll a cusom one.

```
PS C:\> $now = get-date
PS C:\> $then = $now.AddHours(-3)
PS C:\> $now.ToString("u")
2013-06-03 18:43:29Z
PS C:\> $then.ToString("u")
2013-06-03 15:43:29Z
```